# jquery : time operations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 time inputs as 7:07:02 and 7:00

How can I find the difference between these two,I prefer to use jquery, Is there any jquery plugins available for this ? ( please let me know if you know other solutions for this )

Thanks a lot

Comment: What would be the expected result in this case?

Comment: guys I expect 0:07:02 as output, thanks

Comment: It is basic math operations, what is hard about multiplying and dividing some numbers by 60?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

```
(Date.parse('7:07:02') - Date.parse('7:00')) / 1000; // => 422 seconds
```

Comment: @matt why to use a any javascript library for this , we can just achieve with javascript right.

Comment: @gov it all boils down to his use cases.  We can't read his mind, but already in his example he gives 2 different formats for time.  Will it ever include a date? AM or PM? Who knows.  I would ask you - why write all the JS to properly parse dates and times when someone else has already done the heavy lifting for you? Date functionality in JS is already pretty sparse.  DateJS makes working with date and times in JS trivial.

Comment: sorry guys,  first value : 7:00 second value : 7:07:02 result: 0:07:02 thank you Matt, hope you can fix this too

Comment: You want the result to be the string value "0:07:02" or a numerical value representing 7 minutes and 2 seconds?

Comment: either string value or numerical value,I just want to show the result on a input box after user types the second value, 7:07:02 .first value comes from database Thanks a again,

Comment: @Thomas John. The result above is in seconds (or, if you don't divide by 1000, milliseconds).  If you plan on using DateJS, I recommend reading the documentation.  It includes information on how to convert dates to strings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want jquery. Just javascript will accomplish this. Change the two times to Dates and then add/subtract them as you like. Finally convert back to the date format that you want to use.